# How to enforce (with a warning) that parent functions are called by the children that override them?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `Parent` class with many children:

```
class Parent(Object):
    def function(self):
        do_something()

class Child1(Parent):
    def function(self):
        super(Child1, self).function()
        do_something_else_1()

class Child2(Parent):
    def function(self):
        do_something_else_2()
```

and so on.

It is almost always the case that `do_something()` should be called by the children. I would like to throw a warning if someone writes a child class without making the `super` call, such as in `Child2`. How do I go about that?

Comment: Do you want to raise that warning when the class is defined (at import time), when the user instantiates the class or when the method `function` is called?

Comment: Hmm. That is a great question that I haven't thought about. Where would it make sense for this warning to be raised? A normal user should never see this warning. I would think it'd be best if it's raised at import time, because there's no guarantee that the function is called.

Comment: If the end user is not supposed to see the warning, raising at import time would probably be the right thing to do. But  you should check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224896/force-child-class-to-call-parent-method-when-overriding-it) out first. Instead of enforcing your requirement, the best idea is probably to document it in plain sight to the user of your library.

Comment: I definitely see the point. I'll probably just document it. For the sake of curiosity though, how would I do that check at the import? The examples in that question seem to do it at the time of the function call.

Comment: I probably would have done [what Jim says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35142796/2199801) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First solution that's not hidden from the end-user:

Another not so full-proof way you might be able to go about this is by using a decorator which takes a function and checks its innards. What this decorator can do is check the `func_code.co_names` (`func.__code__.co_names` in Py3) to see if `super` along with the function name `func.func_name` (`func.__name__` in Py3) are present:

```
def require_super(func):
    f_name = func.func_name
    other_names = func.func_code.co_names
    if not all(val in other_names for val in [f_name, 'super']):
        warnings.warn("Super must be defined on function: " + f_name)
    return func
```

`f_name` is of course the function name defined.

`other_names` [*is a tuple containing the names which aren’t covered by any of the other fields (they are not local variables, they are not free variables, etc) used by the bytecode.*](https://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/07/03/pythons-innards-code-objects/)

`all(val in other_names for val in [f_name, 'super'])` will go through the names in `other_names` and check if `f_name` and `super` are present as entries. *If this **isn't** the case* it will issue a warning and then return the function unchanged, *if it is the case*, it returns the function.

When a user defines a class and doesn't provide a super call the `warning` is going to be raised during execution of the class body:

```
class foo(Parent):
    @require_super
    def function(self, arg):
        s = "No super"
```

This returns a warning of the form:

```
UserWarning: Super must be defined on function: function
```

Which you can log/ignore do anything you need with it.

This definitely seems fragile and it probably is. You could alter the decorator `require_super` to do some more intelligent checks. Remember, everything about the (class) function is present in the underlying `code` object, hack on it and you'll be able to do pretty much anything you want.

---

#### Second solution Hidden from the end user:

A way to do this behind the scenes is by using a metaclass. By doing this you can get a snap-shot of any classes defined with a `type(cls) = mymetaclass` and any other classes that subclass the original class. Our already defined function `require_super` can now just become a `staticmethod` (not necessary but why not) of the metaclass and we'll call it to check a function object every-time a new class is defined.

Let's first define our meta class:

```
class requireMeta(type):

    _requiredFunc = 'function'

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        # base classes, dictionary of functions
        bases, funcs = args[1], args[2]
        # skip the check for the base class
        # which inherits from object
        if not bases[0].__name__ == 'object':  
            try:
                # run requireSuper for the function 'function'
                cls.requireSuper(funcs[cls._requiredFunc])
            except KeyError:
                # if it doesn't exist, complain.
                warnings.warn("Function: {} must be defined!".format(cls._requiredFunc))            
        return super(requireMeta, cls).__new__(cls, *args)

    @staticmethod
    def requireSuper(func):
        """
        Functionality is the same as described already.
        """
        f_name = func.func_name
        other_names = func.func_code.co_names
        if not all(val in other_names for val in [f_name, 'super']):
            warnings.warn("Super must be defined on function: " + f_name)
        return func
```

So what our metaclass does here when a `__new__` class is created is: it takes its bases and the functions it has defined, checks if the bases don't contain `object` (there's a discrepancy here for the case of Py3) meaning the class defined is a subclass and tries to pass the function with the name `'function'` to `require_super`. If the function doesn't exist a warning is raised; if it does the same functionality provided by `require_super` is performed.

Now, the additional change required here is assigning the type of `Parent` to be equal to `requireMeta`, this is done via the `__metaclass__` attribute:

```
class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = requireMeta

    def function(self):
        print("Doing Something")
```

in Py3 the same thing is done with `class Parent(metaclass = requireMeta)` and nothing more :-).

When Python discovers this class definition, it's going to eventually issue the call `requireMeta.__new__` with the appropriate parameters. Good thing is, this call is made for `Parent` *and for any subclasses of `Parent`* so your subclasses `Child1` and `Child2` can stay as they are and the check is going to happen when the metaclasses `__new__` is invoked:

```
class Child1(Parent):
   def function(self):
       super(Child1, self).function()
       do_something_else_1()
```

executes smoothly with no warning raised. On the other hand this definition:

```
class Child2(Parent):
    def function(self):
        do_something_else_2()
```

Will print:

```
 UserWarning: Super must be defined on function: function
```

While a definition without `function` defined:

```
class Child3(Parent):
    pass
```

will print:

```
UserWarning: Function: function must be overriden!
```

Comment: would be nice to do this via a metaclass on the parent class, which would check all its subclasses methods on start and not at runtime

Comment: @Apero that would be smarter and more fitting in this case, especially if you need this sort of check 'hidden' from the end-user. I might just edit this answer at some point to add a meta approach. (unless if you want to whip up an answer)

Comment: that's kinda what abc.ABCMeta does in its register method, to check for methods declared with the decorator @abstractmethod

Comment: go for it mate, no issue

Answer (score 4):

One way you could achieve something similar is to provide an interface for the child classes that 'forces' the writer of a subclass to get the base behaviour, without even having to call super:

```
class Parent(object):
    def _extra_functions(self):
        # Override me in derived classes!
        pass

    def function(self):
        # Don't override me
        do_something()
        self.extra_functions()

class Child1(Parent):
    def _extra_functions(self):
        do_something_else_1()

class Child2(Parent):
    def _extra_functions(self):
        do_something_else_2()
```

This is still reliant on the writer of the subclasses behaving the way you want. No matter how hard you try, any 'solution' will always be able to be worked around by a clever developer, so if you absolutely must have this then python probably isn't the right language. However, this (or other answers) make it very clear how the developers are *supposed* to extend this class.