# python - remain in base class when calling parent method from child

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have the following base class:

```
class ClientRepo(Repository):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__clientList = []

    def hasClientWithId(self, clientId):
        for client in self.__clientList:
            if client.getId() == clientId:
                return True
        return False

    def addClient(self, client):
        if type(client).__name__ == 'ClientDAO':
            if not self.hasClientWithId(client.getId()):
                client.setClientId(self.__maximumIndexInClientList() + 1)
                self.__clientList.append(client)
            else:
                raise ObjectAlreadyInCollectionException
        else:
            raise TypeError
```

which basically only holds a list and can add a ClientDAO to it.

And the following, which derives from it:

```
class ClientFileRepository(ClientRepo):

    def __init__(self, fileName) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.__fileName = fileName
        self.__file = None

    def hasClientWithId(self, clientId):
        self.__loadRepo()
        hasClientWithId = super().hasClientWithId(clientId)
        super().clean()
        return hasClientWithId

    def addClient(self, client):
        self.__loadRepo()
        super().addClient(client)
        self.__storeRepo()
        super().clean()

    def __loadFileReadMode(self):
        self.__file = open(self.__fileName, "r")

    def __loadFileWriteMode(self):
        self.__file = open(self.__fileName, "w")

    def __closeFile(self):
        self.__file.close()

    def __loadRepo(self):
        self.__loadFileReadMode()
        for line in self.__file:
            splitLine = line.split()
            clientToAdd = ClientDAO(splitLine[1])
            clientToAdd.setClientId(int(splitLine[0]))
            super().addClientWithId(clientToAdd)
        self.__closeFile()

    def __storeRepo(self):
        self.__loadFileWriteMode()
        self.__file.write("")
        for client in super().getList():
            self.__file.write(self.clientToString(client))
        self.__closeFile()

    def clientToString(self, clientDAO):
        return str(clientDAO.getId()) + " " + clientDAO.getName() + "\n"
```

a class which should load the list from a file, call `addClient` from parent, and store the updated list in the file. The problem is that after child class loads the file in `addClient`, it calls the method in the parent, which calls `hasClientWithId`, from the child, again. But I want it to call `hasClientWithId`, from the parent, that is, the context it is in. Can I achieve that?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the issue. If you don't want to call the child method, then you should have not overwritten it on the child class, so it would call the right one, or change the name of the function `hasClientWithId` on the child class. 
Explain what you're trying, so I can see if I can help you

Comment: so. when I call addClient in child, i want to go (after loading from file) to the super().addClient. there it calls hasClientWithId, but from the child. I want that child calling addClient use hasClientWithId from parent. hasClientWithId in child is for using it from "outside"

Comment: Without further analysis, I'd say that it doesn't seem a good idea, as it seems to be a flaw in logic, and for me to help you with the code, I need more info on the use case you're developing for. 
In any case, I suggest taking a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34225828/10642035

Comment: at the end of the day the question is, how can I use the already existent code from parent in child class? that is, how can i just add the files logic in child?

Comment: @DaniPop Inheritance is not the right tool to achieve your goal. Instead simply keep a local field of type `ClientRepo` in your `ClientFileRepository` class. This way you will be using the "unmodified" logic of the `ClientRepo` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of several ways to achieve your goal. I ranked them from worst to best

**1. Exactly what you asked for**

You wanted that `ClientRepo.addClient` calls `ClientRepo.hasClientWithId` instead of `ClientFileRepository.hasClientWithId`. It is possible to enforce that:

```
class ClientRepo(Repository): 
    def addClient(self, client): 
        if type(client).__name__ == 'ClientDAO': 
            if not ClientRepo.hasClientWithId(self, client.getId()): 
                client.setClientId(self.__maximumIndexInClientList() + 1)
                self.__clientList.append(client) 
            else: 
                raise ObjectAlreadyInCollectionException
        else: 
            raise TypeError
```

This is not a good approach, because it's unintuitive and breaks the principles of OOP. Any other programmer writing a subclass of `ClientRepo` that overrides `hasClientWithId` would expect that this will have an effect for every call to `hasClientWithId` even inside of `addClient`

**2. Let `ClientFileRepository` decide which function to use**

Add a variable

```
self.__isFileOpen = False
```

in `ClientFileRepository.__init__`, set it to `True` when you open the file and to `False` when you close the file. Then change the `hasClientWithId` within `ClientFileRepository` to

```
def hasClientWithId(self, clientId):
    if not self.__isFileOpen:
        self.__loadRepo()
        result = super().hasClientWithId(clientId)
        super().clean() 
        return result
    else:
        return super().hasClientWithId(clientId)
```

to avoid opening the same file again. This works, but it is pretty difficult to write new functions for this class, because you always need to be aware if the function call is a call from within your class or from somewhere else. Also this seems pretty inefficient, because you read and write the entire file, even when you only add one client.

**3. Read the file only once and modify the underlying `ClientRepo`**

```
class ClientFileRepository(ClientRepo): 
    def __init__(self, fileName) -> None: 
        super().__init__() 
        self.__fileName = fileName 
        self.__loadRepo()

    # No hasClientWithId needed

    def addClient(self, client):
        super().addClient(client)
        self.__storeRepo()

    def __loadRepo(self):
        with open(self.__filename) as file:
            for line in file: 
                splitLine = line.split() 
                clientToAdd = ClientDAO(splitLine[1])
                clientToAdd.setClientId(int(splitLine[0])) 
                super().addClientWithId(clientToAdd) 

    def __storeRepo(self): 
        with open(self.__filename, "w") as file:
            file.write("") 
            for client in super().getList():
                file.write(self.clientToString(client))
```

This obviously assumes that the file is not changed by someone else between calls to `addClient` and the program still overwrites the entire file for every `addClient`. If this is a problem for you it is best to be explicit and make `loadRepo` and `storeRepo` public. Then the programmer using this class can decide when loading and saving are necessary and useful. You can use context managers for this.

**Extra: Read and save the file for every method**

You can use function decorators to use solution 2 without writing the same code for every function:

```
import functools

def loadAndStore(function):
    @functoools.wraps(function)
    def wrappedFunction(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__isFileOpen:
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.__isFileOpen = True
            self.__loadRepo()
            try:
                return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e: # Only catch expected exceptions
                raise
            finally:
                self.__storeRepo()
                self.clear() # some cleanup
                self.__isFileOpen = False
    return wrappedFunction

class ClientFileRepository(ClientRepo): 
    def __init__(self, fileName) -> None: 
        super().__init__() 
        self.__fileName = fileName
        self.__isFileOpen = False

    @loadAndStore
    def hasClientWithId(self, clientId):
        return super().hasClientWithId(clientId)

    @loadAndStore
    def addClient(self, client):
        super().addClient(client)

    def __loadRepo(self):
        with open(self.__filename) as file:
            for line in file: 
                splitLine = line.split() 
                clientToAdd = ClientDAO(splitLine[1])
                clientToAdd.setClientId(int(splitLine[0])) 
                super().addClientWithId(clientToAdd) 

    def __storeRepo(self): 
        with open(self.__filename, "w") as file:
            file.write("") 
            for client in super().getList():
                file.write(self.clientToString(client))
```

Be careful here, using this is not very intuitive. For example `self.__isFileOpen` is defined in `__init__`, but none of the methods below directly use it. Instead its use is hidden in the `loadAndStore` decorator.

Some quick hints at the end:

- `type(client).__name__ == 'ClientDAO'` is bad practice. Use `isinstance(client, ClientDAO)` to fully adopt OOP
- If this is not part of a bigger project with given naming conventions use [the python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Using private variables like `__fileName` is generally considered unnecessary, just prefix the variable with one underscore to indicate "internal use". The same is true for functions.

Comment: that's awesome! thank you. just a little question before closing the question and marked as answered: let's assume i still load and store in every operation. is there a way to do that somehow implicit for every method i need, without loading and storing explicitly for everyone?

Comment: @AvramPop I added some new code regarding your question.