# Perform an action when a child method is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a base class which describe what a encoding system looks like:

```py
class Encoder(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self._encode_time = []
        self._decode_time = []

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def encode(self, decoded_data: DataMapper, **kwargs) -> Tuple[DataMapper, MetadataCollector]:
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def decode(self, encoded_data: DataMapper, metadata: MetadataCollector, **kwargs) -> DataMapper:
        pass
```

This class is inherited by many other classes to describe different encoders.
Now, I would like to add statistics to these models. For example, I would like to store the compression time  of encoding/decoding each time the function is called.

For example, something like this :

```py
class Encoder(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self._encode_time = []
        self._decode_time = []

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def encode(self, decoded_data: DataMapper, **kwargs) -> Tuple[DataMapper, MetadataCollector]:
        t1 = time.clock()
        child_call(decoded_data, **kwargs)
        self._encode_time.append(time.clock() - t1)
```

How can I do something like this without changing the code of all my children classes ?

Comment: Specifically, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65307524/16177247) might be of interest. You would only have to change the call to the methods.

Comment: you could define `encode()` as normal function with `time()` and it would run abstract `_encode()` - and other class would have to overwrite `_encode()`